# How to choose the element that we need for Crosstab Table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, contingency

I have a dataset which I have to use calculate the chi-squre test for it.
For the explanatory variable Gender, and the outcome variable Vist. For gender I have Male, Female, and NotAnswered. The NotAnswered number is huge but I don't want it, if I use

```
pd.crosstab(df['Sex'], df['Visit'], margins=True)
```

I will have 3 rows and 2 columns, Is there anyway to omit the "NotAnswered" from the crosstab's result? I only want my crosstab table has two rows, Female and Male.

code to generate sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sexes = np.concatenate([np.random.choice(["Male", "Female"], 90), ["NotAnswered"] * 10])
np.random.shuffle(sexes)

visits = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)

# create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Sex": sexes,
    "Visit": visits
})
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Tanx, add the code for generating a sample code.

Comment: just drop the `NotAnswered` rows, e.g. `df = df.loc[df.Sex != 'NotAnswered']`

Comment: @tdy Thank You very much. I thought != only use to omit columns.